# backend JSP program?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm thinking about a "back end server" runs all the time(first store data on data service) to give data to main page(index.jsp).

Can I have a JSP running all the time just as a back end server that fetches data providing to the main page? Or servlet as well?

Comment: @Loc Could you be more specific?

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do so your misconception of how it will/should work with JSP/Servlets can be corrected.

Comment: The way you've described it so far, your "back end server" that "store[s] data" sounds like a database server. Is this an attempt to reinvent the wheel rather than just install mysql?